# Cannot fork an older heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a ruby on rails app on heroku that I wanted to make some updates to. I was hoping to fork the app and test my changes on a new staging clone before I update the live site.

When I try the command:

```
heroku fork -a source-app new-staging-app
```

I get the error:

```
!    'fork' is not a heroku command.
```

And when I use "heroku help", fork does not appear as one of the choices.

When I'm signed in to another account and working on a more recent app, the fork command is available as a command.

The app I'm trying to fork is on the cedar stack and it's currently using rails 3.2.11.

Any idea why 'fork' might not be available with this app?

Comment: Verify your heroku toolbelt https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command#installing-the-heroku-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'fork' command was added to the heroku toolbelt in 2013. Install the latest version of the heroku toolbelt on the account in question to be able to use the fork feature: https://toolbelt.heroku.com